# Remove VBA and save as csv in certain path

Tags: excel, vba

I have and excel sheet (template) and I want to add button to ask three simple questions, then save the file as csv in a certain directory and removing the vba from it too. Also, is it possible to save the file name as the full name entered in step 1?

```
Sub clickhere()

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(3, 1) = Application.inputbox("Insert Full Name:")
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(2, 8) = Application.inputbox("Insert Start date mm/dd/yyyy:")
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(3, 1) = Application.inputbox("Insert comment:")
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "fullname_from_line_1.csv"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify the full path and include the `FileFormat` option - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: FWIW, once you get the SaveAs csv working, that will remove any VBA (in the saved file), so no need for an extra step.

Comment: @braX thank you. that worked. Now I need to see how to save the file as the full name entered in step 1

Comment: `Filename:= "PathHere\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Cells(3, 1).Value &  ".csv"`

Comment: Also, it looks like you are asking for a full filename, storing it in cell(3,1) and then asking for a comment, and storing it in the same cell, overwriting what the user entered as a full name. is that intentional?

Comment: And keep in mind that there are certain characters that cannot be used in a filename, so in general, asking the user to enter anything they want as a filename is asking for future problems with the code.

Comment: @braX Thank you that helped!